# How to install something to my spiral staircases so that I can separate two floors?

Tags: interior, design

I’d like to do something to my spiral staircases so I can separate my second floor and first floor with a door or something. The reason being I don’t want my pets to go downstairs as we use our first floor to run business and second floor is our living area. Anyone has any idea? Much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How much do you want change the look?  To block a stairway from pets, will need a door with walls.  Where the picture is showing, will need at least two, maybe three walls, so a door will stop pets.  Pets are like kids, if there is an opening they will go though it.

Comment: @crip659 Depends on the size of the pets...or the kids. A gate or fence structure may well suffice, and provide better visuals.

Comment: I'd be fond of a rotating fan type of device. Collapse when closed, extend and tension fabric when open.

Comment: @fred_dot_u   Something like the iris on stargate?

Comment: That would be cool, indeed. There are plenty of iris devices constructed by makers on the 'net, but I was thinking of something anchored on the vertical at the 90 degree floor portion, radially extending like a hand-held fan.

Comment: @fred_dot_u  OP does seem to need something outside of the box to keep the look.  Seems like at least three or four sections to block off with basic ideas.

Comment: You'd need four gates because your railings aren't to code. If you brought it up to code and actually safe, then you'd need a single pet/kid gate, which is available at the store.... I thought this was going to be about stopping air flow, for which you're SoL anyway afaik. - **Four gates and a crap load of big ass zip ties.** Or four grand in railings, one gate, and a few zip ties.

Comment: This is unsafe for children, so it's unsafe for your pets, no? As Crip says, they *will* find a way if there is one. This 'iris' thing (that doesn't exist?) people are talking about would probably cost $10k. And then you still wouldn't have blasters on your stair case, or the railing, and if you leave it open someone or something could get hurt.

Comment: It is a hole in the floor, where anyone can fall into from all sides

Comment: When was the last time you played your violin?   The one in the corner collecting dust.

Comment: Need another photo - it's not clear how one is supposed to exit the stairs onto this level.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is my idea.

Very elegant, with 100% closing up the hole.

It works like a Folding hand fan.

[image: fan]

You probably need 4 fan slices, so when fully open it wont interfere with passing true.

[image: slices]

Here is the side view

[image: side view]

You can also go cheap, and DIY stile, cut a cloth per hole dimension. Make one rotating flange (out of wood), attach a rod to it and fix it on the other end.

How to make the flange? Take a pice of play wood and drill a hole in in in size of the center post (probably 2- 3 inches). Cut in in half, now you have 2 halves.  Screw in the rod.

Comment: How would you open and close this from below as you're climbing the stairs?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact >> Glad you asked, a stick in vertical position mounted on the first slice.